# Why can't this be another structural isomer of ethanol?

Tags: organic-chemistry, structural-formula

Are the two structures depicting the same molecule? Why? Why not?

[image: Ethanol "isomers"]

Comment: If ethanol was flat, it would make sense, but it isn't.

Comment: They can be stereo isomers instead. See https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/11/Ethanol-3d-stick-structure.svg/266px-Ethanol-3d-stick-structure.svg.png for 3d structure of ethanol.

Comment: If ethanol was static, this would be true, but it isn't.

Comment: There could be atropoisomers if rotation was blocked but it would need very low temperature to try to separate what is normally rotamers of ethanol.

Answer (score 18):

Try to imagine it in a 3D fashion. You can look it at [molcalc.org](http://molcalc.org/calculation/006f345b78127258186ad02dcf30e0ae). The molecule rotates around the $\ce{C-C}$ bond converting one structure into the other. These rotations are very fast.

Another point is, that the representations you chose are 2D, so the could still represent the same molecule:

[image: same molecule different angles]

Comment: I changed the URL for ethanol model, the previous one gives error 404 (probably they change the part in the address that looks like a hash from time to time).

Comment: @andselisk thanks. Maybe I should come back to this again and add an animated gif, or even link to some other provider as a backup. The Pittsburgh repository comes to mind, but I guess that was still in its infancy when writing this answer.